# Delete specific Documents at DocuSign using envelop ID (Assembly DocuSign.eSign)

Tags: c#, docusignapi, document, delete-file

I am using  DocuSign.eSign dll in C#.
I want to delete documents(Envelop) from Docusign

I have used method exposed by "EnvelopesApi" class like "DeleteDocuments". But it essentially delete document from draft envelop but I want delete any envelop generated at docusign.

```
EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
    {
        EnvelopeId = envelopId
    };
    envelopesApi.DeleteDocuments(accountId, envelopId,                                                          
 envelopeDefinition);
```

After calling this method, I expect documents(envelop) to delete from DocuSign but I yet can retrieve documents using "ListDocuments" method. please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options here, so you may want to clarify what exactly you're looking for.

1. Delete an Envelope. Deleting an envelope doesn't actually remove it from the DocuSign system, it just removes the user's pointer to it so it no longer appears in their Manage tab. To Delete an envelope, use the [Folders::MoveEnvelopes](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Folders/Folders/moveEnvelopes) method with a folder ID of "recyclebin". Note that if the Sender deletes an In Process envelope it will be voided.

   This example shows how to delete two envelopes:

   ```
       FoldersApi foldersApi = new FoldersApi(apiClient.Configuration);

       FoldersRequest foldersRequest = new FoldersRequest();
       foldersRequest.EnvelopeIds = new List<string>();
       foldersRequest.EnvelopeIds.Add("000-111-222");
       foldersRequest.EnvelopeIds.Add("333-444-555");

       foldersApi.MoveEnvelopes(accountId, "recyclebin", foldersRequest);
   ```
2. Purge an Envelope. Purged envelopes are fully removed from DocuSign, only a stub record and the Certificate of Completion will remain. More information purging is available here: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-purge-envelopes
   Note that purging an envelope sends notifications to all recipients with DocuSign accounts, and there is a two week delay to allow them to access the envelope before it is removed.

   To queue an envelope for Purge, the [Envelopes::Update](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/update) method should be used. When calling this method via the SDK, it's recommended that you create an empty Envelope object, set the PurgeState there, and then apply that object with the Update() method.

   ```
       EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient.Configuration);
       string envelopeId = "000-111-222";

       Envelope purgeEnvelope = new Envelope
       {
           PurgeState = "documents_queued" //change to "documents_and_metadata_queued" to also remove recipient info
       };

       envelopesApi.Update(accountId, envelopeId, purgeEnvelope);
   ```

Comment: I am already using second option. But the issue is docusign throws an exception for In Process envelop .it only woks for completed envelop. In My case envelop might be in process..Please let me know if you have any solution for it.

Comment: In Process envelopes cannot be purged, and you cannot both void and purge an envelope in the same API call. You'll need to void the envelope with one API call and then queue it for purge it with another.
`Envelope voidEnvelope = new Envelope
            {                Status = "voided",
                VoidedReason = "To be purged",
            };`